# Returning HTML response without API gateway in AWS Lambda for Node template

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am trying to experiment with AWS Lambda and I am using Serverless CLI for my deployment. I am using aws-nodejs template to generate my project folder.

This is the handler.js code:

```
'use strict';

module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: {
      "message":
      'Hello World! Today is '+new Date().toDateString()
    }
  };

  // Use this code if you don't use the http event with the LAMBDA-PROXY integration
  // return { message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!', event };
};
```

I am getting a successful response in JSON format. I am trying to tweak it to return HTML response. Should I change the content-type for that? If so how?

I have gone through the below questions:

- [Get aws lambda response as an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779868/get-aws-lambda-response-as-an-html-page)
- [Return HTML from AWS API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614198/return-html-from-aws-api-gateway)

and a few others as well. But all of them are using the web console and the API gateway which I am not using.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add the content headers for html

```
return {
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
  },
  body: '<p>Look ma, its sending html now</p>',
}
```

Also, this is in one of the [serverless examples in their github repo](https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/master/aws-node-serve-dynamic-html-via-http-endpoint/handler.js).

Answer (score 0):

This works, try it. I have tested it with Lambda Function URL or with Lambda as Target for Application Load balancer

```
export const handler = async(event) => {
   
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: '<h1>HTML from Lambda without API GW</h1>',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        }
    };
    return response;
};
```