# Getting double quotes when returning html

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, hapi.js, serverless, hapi

I have below route to return privacy policy for my app.

```
const html = `<html><body><div>dsfdsfsfdsfsfsdfdsf</div></body></html>`
const handler = (request, reply) => {
  try {
    return reply(html)
  } catch (err) {
    return reply({ success: false, message: err.message, data: [] })
  }
}

const routeConfig = {
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/privacy-policy',
  config: {
    description: 'Creates a task.',
    notes: ['On success, returns { "data": [ { "tasks" } ]}'],
    handler
  }
}
```

However when I am returning the html content I am getting double quotes at the start and at the end of my content.

How can I remove them? Thank you

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty But where I can add that option?

Comment: Where is my html content in the solution?

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty Still getting double quotes buddy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get aws lambda response as an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779868/get-aws-lambda-response-as-an-html-page)

Comment: @GabrielBleu Thank you very much. But its hapijs. I have reply function How can I add that option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things here -

```
// 1. You can reply with html as json`
return reply({html});

// This will this html in a json and you can use this in frontend receiving a json response 
// 2. You can send the html (file) as a html response
return reply.view('htmlFile.html');
//If you want to render the html
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting quotes in start and end of the `html` because of you are returning it as `string`. What you can do is, rather returning the `replay` in the string you can return the Html. One more thing is not to forget the response header `Content-Type` as `text/html`. once you set the response header, the client browser will understand the response and start parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to set `Content-Type` to `text/html`.